# Coffee compiler works with a different file order in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, coffeescript, pipeline

I run this command from a directory containing coffee files

```
coffee --watch --compile --bare --join ../js/output.js .
```

The coffee files are used in a different order depending on OS. Its probably due to the difference in Alphabetical sorting of file names in Ubuntu and Windows.
For Example, if on windows the above command translates to

```
coffee --watch --compile --bare --join ../js/output.js a.coffee A.coffee b.coffee c.coffee
```

On Ubuntu, its roughly working like

```
coffee --watch --compile --bare --join ../js/output.js a.coffee b.coffee c.coffee A.coffee
```

Any solutions that ensure the same compile order on any OS? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Applications of windows do not distinguish uppercase/lowercase of filenames. In Ubuntu and other unix/linux ditinguish uppercase/lowercase. In windows, file "A.coffee" and "a.coffee" can not be existed in a directry/folder. If "A.coffee" and "a.coffee" in your source files in Ubuntu, one of them will be disappear when they copied into windows system.  This might make difference for you.

Comment: Actually there are no files with the same name but the order is changing between windows and ubuntu due to this different approach to the case of filename.

Comment: Unix directories aren't sorted in any particular way, you get things back in whatever order is most convenient for the filesystem. I doubt `coffee` is bothering to sort them itself so you should expect them to be in a pretty much random order. If you need them in a specific order, do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I see that no one else is facing the same issue. I guess I've to make the solution myself. Thanks for your inputs! :)